# Unable to deploy Meteor's sample app and get weird error

Tags: meteor, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a sample app from the tutorial on the Meteor website using the following line

```
meteor deploy simple-todos.meteor.com
```

but I get the following message:

> Sorry, that site belongs to a different user.
>   You are currently logged in as valerierickert.
>
> Either have the site owner use 'meteor authorized --add' to add you as an authorized
>   developer for the site, or switch to an authorized account with
>   'meteor login'.

Then I logged in and still got the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that someone already deployed a Meteor App at this address, which is not surprising because it's the name showcased in the official Meteor tutorial.

http://simple-todos.meteor.com/

You just need to choose another identifier like `valerier-todos.meteor.com` which is probably not taken at the moment.